# Identifying a component in a circuit diagram

Tags: operational-amplifier, schematics, temperature

[image]

I'm a beginner when it comes to electronic circuits and came across this schematic diagram for a class exercise. It's my first time coming across this certain component (encircled). It does say it's an LM35 temperature sensor, but the LM35 only has 3 pins, while this one apparently has 5. Any idea what it is?

If it'll help, here are some details about the exercise:

- Title of exercise is Temperature Modeling
- Materials/Components to be used include: a 12v brake lamp with socket, lm35 temp sensor, lf353 op-amp, mc4741 op-amp, tip35c transistor, and some resistors and bourns trimmer
- The objective is to record the output voltage per time interval

Comment: I think these are two components - a lamp and a temp sensor measuring it's temperature.

Comment: I see. I kinda had that idea too, but I wasn't entirely sure. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I expect that the box is the LM35, while the thing to the left of the box is the brake light.  That symbol is often used for incandescent lamps.

Since your exercise deals with temperature modelling, the light bulb is used to heat up the LM35, so should be in contact with it. (and there's nothing else in the diagram that could be the brake light.)